# Salesforce Messaging.SingleEmailMessage Test Class

Tags: unit-test, singleemailmessage

Can anyone help me get test coverage for Messaging.SingleEmailMessage?

I'm using email template. Whenever a Case closes, it should send email to `Contact.Email` and bcc emails of the custom label.

How to assert singleemailmessage in test class?

Answer (score 3):

One way to assert on email sent in APEX is to look at the email limits for the transaction. Between your startTest and stopTest you would include an integer to assign `Limits.getEmailInvocations();` which will tell you how many invoked emails there are.

```
Test.startTest();
ClassBeingTested.methodWithEmailCall();
Integer i = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
Test.stopTest();

System.assertEquals(1,i);
```

Comment: I have never been able to get this to work; instead I use [this pattern](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/23/apexmocks-and-email/)

Comment: I've never had any problem with it. Transition cost would be extremely high for a new developer to pick up fflib just for one test.